# Flattening a Sub-Array in a Powershell Object, including parent object property

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, projection

Given the following JSON

```
[
  {
    "key": "James",
    "things": [
      {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "PRD"
      },
      {
        "id": 124,
        "name": "PRE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Susan",
    "things": [
      {
        "id": 125,
        "name": "PRF"
      },
      {
        "id": 126,
        "name": "PRG"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Which, I've easily converted into a Powershell object:

```
$json = '[{"key":"James", "things":[{"id":123,"name":"PRD"},{"id":124,"name":"PRE"}]},{"key":"Susan", "things":[{"id":125,"name":"PRF"},{"id":126,"name":"PRG"}]}]'

$obj = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

How do I flatten the sub-array `things` and include the `key` from the parent object, so that my result set is

```
key    id name
---    -- ----
James 123 PRD  
James 124 PRE  
Susan 125 PRF
Susan 126 PRG
```

I've used the following to flatten the sub-array:

```
$obj | % { $_.things}
```

Which returns me

```
 id name
 -- ----
123 PRD  
124 PRE  
125 PRF
126 PRG
```

But, I can't quite figure out what to do next.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: FYI, in case you didn't knew `$obj | % { $_.things}  `  can be replaced by `$obj.things` . Powershell will do its thing, enumarate the things  and produce the same output in either cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loop into each key, then loop into each things, since you want 1 result per thing, and build a PSObject using the current key, id and name.

Here you go.

```
# initial code sample
$json = '[{"key":"James", "things":[{"id":123,"name":"PRD"},{"id":124,"name":"PRE"}]},{"key":"Susan", "things":[{"id":125,"name":"PRF"},{"id":126,"name":"PRG"}]}]'
$obj = $json | ConvertFrom-Json 

# Loop needed to flatten the object.
foreach ($i in $obj) {
    foreach ($t in $i.things) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            key  = $i.key
            id   = $t.id
            name = $t.name
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
key    id name
---    -- ----
James 123 PRD
James 124 PRE
Susan 125 PRF
Susan 126 PRG
```

Comment: Hmmmm "Cannot convert value to type "System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives+InternalPSCustomObject". Only core types are supported in this language 
mode."

Comment: @JamesWiseman That is because you are working in constrained mode. As far as I know, this mode is very limited in what you can do. You might be able to do a pipeldouble pipeline for each with the use of pipeline variable and produce your output through a select statement that use a calculated property for the key... Not sure if calculated properties work in constrained mode though. I'll check when I am back in front of the PC.

Comment: Turns out it was my local windows security policy. Running the Script in Powershell ISE with elevated 'Admin' privs fixed this. Interesting thought experiment though, achieving this with more primitive powershell.

Answer (score 1):

you can use built-in flattening with select as follows:

($json | ConvertFrom-Json) | Select-Object key -ExpandProperty things